# how to turn off letter buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got a bunch of letter buttons in code below:

```
<?php
    $a = range("A","Z");
?>

<table id="answerSection">
    <tr>

<?php
    $i = 1;
    foreach($a as $key => $val){
        if($i%7 == 1) echo"<tr><td>";
        echo"<input type=\"button\" onclick=\"btnclick(this);\" value=\"$val\" id=\"answer".$val."\" name=\"answer".$val."Name\" class=\"answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff\">";      
        if($i%7 == 0) echo"</td></tr>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now the code below is able to turn on an answer button:

```
$('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

But what I want to do is to be able to turn some answer buttons on and turn the other answer buttons off.

For example if the Answer is A, then I want button "A" to turn on which the above line of code does but I want all of the other letter buttons to turn off. How can I turn off the other letter buttons?

The code here will turn off the letter buttons `addClass("answerBtnsOff");`,

UPDATE:

I have a little problem as well. If the "Answer" is A, then the letter button "A" is turned on which is fine, but if the Answer is "B D", then it should turn on letter buttons "B" and "D" but instead it doesn't turn any buttons on. Does anybody know why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following selector combination:

```
$('#answer'+btn1+', #answer'+btn2).addClass("answerBtnsOn").removeClass("answerBtnsOff");
$('[id^="answer"]').not('#answer'+btn1+', #answer'+btn2).addClass("answerBtnsOff").removeClass("answerBtnsOff");
```

Comment: See if the edited code works... else please setup a test case on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I won't be abl to put whole code in fiddle because there is a lot of php code to be albe to get the app fully working and php does not work in fiddle. Does your code only work for 2 buttons or is it suppose to work for all letter buttons? Because I am getting an error stating btn1 is undefined

Comment: i never expected you to put up the full code, instead a test case derived from the output that your php file generates. You are dealing with html/js here and thus not interacting with the php at all after the page is generated.

Comment: the code above will only work for 2 buttons as it is meant only to give you an idea of the possibilities.

Comment: the above code has been explained in more detail in @metro's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11380019/476786

Comment: I have tried your code by doing this: `$('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn").removeClass("answerBtnsOff");
$('[id^="answer"]').not('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOff").removeClass("answerBtnsOff");` Problem is that it does not turn off those letter buttons where they don't match the answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13571/discussion-between-bpratik-and-user1490145)

Answer (score 2):

The general pattern would be to reset all the buttons to the off state and then enable only the buttons needed.

```
// reset all answer buttons to the off state
// remove any on/off classes
$("#answerSection").find("button").removeClass("answerBtnsOff").removeClass("answerBtnsOn");

// set all buttons to off
$("#answerSection").find("button").addClass("answerBtnsOff");

// now turn on only the buttons that are valid
$("#answerA").removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
$("#answerB").removeClass("answerBtnsOff").addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

Comment: looking at your example I have managed to turn all buttons off and then turned selected ones on.  Can you please look t the update on my question, I have one little problem when there are multiple answers

Comment: I've updated the 3rd part of the code example `// now turn on only the buttons that are valid` which shows how to enable only the buttons needed.

Comment: No I mean if the answer is "B", then it selects button "B" which is fine, but if there are multiple answers such as "B E", then it turns of all of the buttons, but it doesn't turn on buttons B and E, how do I turn on the buttons if there are multiple answers? It could be any multiple answer, it could be "A D" or "C F H" or even "A B C R T". it only turns on a button if it is a single answer

Comment: At the moment the code im using to turn off all buttons then turn on selected buttons is this:  `$(".answerBtns").removeClass("answerBtnsOn");
  $('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn");`

Comment: I guess I'm not completely understanding the problem statement.

Comment: @user1490145 - go to the [chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13571/discussion-between-bpratik-and-user1490145) where bPratik is and work through the issues.

Answer (score 1):

regarding your update, if i'm understanding you correctly you have a string of space separated answers. if that's the case this code should handle it:

```
var answers = btn.split(" ");
var answer_selector = '#answer'+answers.join(",#answer");
$(".answerBtns").removeClass("answerBtnsOn"); 
$(answer_selector).addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

Answer (score 0):

Um, this may be too simple, but can you just turn them all off first and then turn selected ones back on?

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
$(".answers").addClass("answerBtnsOff");
$('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn");
```

Comment: I will try it, im guessing code is something like: `$('.answerBtns').removeClass('answerBtnsOn').find('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn");`?

Comment: Hi, I tried your edit but it does not turn off the answer buttons, have any other idea to be able to turn the buttons off? I also tried $(".answerBtns").addClass("answerBtnsOff"); but this did not work as well

Comment: it is ok, figured out how to turn them all off and then back on again, this is code:   `$(".answerBtns").removeClass("answerBtnsOn");
  $('#answer'+btn).addClass("answerBtnsOn");`