# jquery if statement is not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I am having problem with my jquery code, I am trying to state that if "Yes" button is on, disable the "No" button, else if the "No" button is on, then disable the "Yes" button, else enable both buttons.

But at the moment do button is being disabled when the other button is turned on, does anyone know why this is?

Below is code:

```
function btnclick(btn)
{
    var context = $(btn).parents('#optionAndAnswer');
    if (context.length == 0) {
        context = $(btn).parents('tr');
    }

$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOff");
$(btn).toggleClass("answerBtnsOn");

    if ($("#answerYes", context).hasClass('.answerBtnsOn')) {
        $("#answerNo", context).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    else if ($("#answerNo", context).hasClass('.answerBtnsOn')) {
        $("#answerYes", context).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }

    else {
    $("#answerYes", context).removeAttr("disabled");
    $("#answerNo", context).removeAttr("disabled");
    }


    return false;
}
```

below is html for both yes and no buttons:

Yes button:

```
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerYesName"   id="answerYes"   type="button"   value="Yes"     onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
```

No Button:

```
<input class="answerBtns answers answerBtnsOff" name="answerNoName"    id="answerNo"        type="button"   value="No"      onclick="btnclick(this);"/>
```

Comment: How is this question any different than your [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379865) [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11417414) [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11423744) on [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1490145/user1490145?tab=questions)

Comment: Oh I did not know about these questions, there is a group of us and we use this account to ask any programming questions we may have, some of our group members must of asked some questions related to this application, but this question is asking how to disable and undisable buttons

Comment: Isn't this type of thing what radio buttons are for? If you want to use push buttons wouldn't it be better to make it that clicking "Yes" automatically deselects "No" rather than disabling it? Otherwise how does the user change their mind?

Comment: @nnnnnn That is a good idea, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont put the `.` in toggleClass/hasClass/removeClass/... you only use them in selectors

Answer (score 0):

Change this `.attr("disabled", "disabled");` to this `.attr("disabled", true);` for both buttons. Plus, you will want to remove the period like @Musa  said

Comment: are you mentioning `.prop("disabled", true);`? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1414366/17447